# Converting between CSS pixel, iOS point, and Android dp

Tags: android, ios, css, mobile-website, screen-resolution

I'm developing a website that will be viewed on mobile devices and I need to determine how large in CSS pixels to make the touch targets.

The Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 2.1 [success criterion 2.5.5](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#target-size) requires touch targets of at least 44 x 44 CSS pixels. [Apple’s Human Interface Guidelines (HIG) for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/#general-layout-considerations) recommends 44 x 44 points and [Google’s Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/design/usability/accessibility.html#layout-typography) recommends 48 x 48 dp.

I'd like to compare the HIG and Material Design guidelines to WCAG. How can I compare CSS pixels, iOS points, and Android dp? Preferably, I'd like to learn how to convert iOS points and Android dp to CSS pixels.

Here is what I understand so far:
iOS points = (width in physical pixels) / [native scale factor](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html) and 1 physical pixel = 1 point on a screen with 163 ppi.
[Android dp](https://material.io/design/layout/density-resolution.html#pixel-density-on-android) = (width in physical pixels * 160) / screen density and 1 physical pixel = 1 dp on a screen with 160 ppi.
1 [CSS pixel](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#px) is equivalent to 1/96th of 1 inch. However, The "CSS ppi" column in the "Compare devices" table at the bottom of [this site](https://www.mydevice.io/) makes me wonder if 1 CSS pixel is not always 1/96th of 1 inch.

I would be satisfied if I could at least convert iOS points and Android dp to CSS pixels given a particular screen, such as that of the [iPad (6th generation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices): 9.7 inch display, 4:3 aspect ratio, 2048 x 1536 px resolution at 264 ppi (retina display).